# How to make a browser with UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have been trying to make a web browser in Swift and it has not been going well.

I was wondering why I got errors whenever I typed `webView.delegate = self`.

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    webView.goBack()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        var text = searchBar.text
        var url = NSURL(string: text)  //type "http://www.apple.com"
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //problem here
webView.delegate = self;

        webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = true
       //problem down here  
        webView.frame = self.view.frame;

        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension:"html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        //        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com")
        //        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        //        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)

        self.searchBar.delegate = self


        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You probably have to have your view controller conform to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol, but without seeing the error, I can't confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning self as the delegate, but your class does not implement the UIWebViewDelegate protocol.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```